# Yum broken in Amazon instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum, rpm

This is an instance launched using Amazon AMI.

when I run yum with anything (search,install, etc), this is what I am getting:

```
yum search yum
error: bad option 'archcolor' at (null):93
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
error: dbiOpen: dbapi 1 not available
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 355, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 174, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 569, in doCommands
    return self.yum_cli_commands[self.basecmd].doCommand(self, self.basecmd, self.extcmds)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.py", line 1682, in doCommand
    return base.search(extcmds)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 1436, in search
    for (po, keys, matched_value) in matching:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3139, in searchGenerator
    lowered=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1274, in searchPrimaryFieldsMultipleStrings
    for hdr, idx in self._get_packages():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1301, in _get_packages
    mi = ts.dbMatch(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/transaction.py", line 58, in dbMatch
    mi = self.ts.dbMatch(*args, **kwds)
_rpm.error: rpmdb open failed
```

Tried google but found nothing that could help. Tried getting the rpm package for all yum  from another similar machine and force installing those packages. that also didn't help. I also tried removing the rpm db files and rebuilding the rpm database which didn't help either.

```
~# cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.09
Kernel \r on an \m
~# uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-2-98 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 16:03:08 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Has anyone faced this before? Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sort of thing is all too common with Amazon Linux, which is one of several reasons I don't recommend using it. Your best bet is to start over with a fresh AMI, whether Amazon Linux or something else.

Comment: I think that's the most logical thing to do. replace rather spending so much time fixing it.

Comment: many of us who use AWS will have some way stored in a file somewhere to be able to reproduce everything we did.  it might simply be the user data script.  when we find a problem, we tweak it to be better, terminate the instance that ran the bad script, and launch a new one with the better one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the RPM database is trashed or corrupt.
Try the following to rebuild the database from the packages already installed on your server: rpm --rebuilddb

Also check if the database files are present in /var/lib/rpm.

Comment: I already tried that which didn't help. going to replace the instance.